# Parsing JSON file to produce and return another JSON with required data

Tags: javascript, php, json, http

I need to parse a given JSON file for events that occur between the start and end time that are passed through an HTTP GET. The events that occur between this range should then be returned as a new JSON encoded response. So far I have come up with two possible solutions. Neither seem to be giving me the expected JSON encoded file.

EDIT: Aside from the script not producing the proper JSON file, I get the following error in the developers console on Chrome: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Solution 1:

```
  $param1 = $_GET['startTime'];
  $param2 = $_GET['endTime'];
  $data = file_get_contents('./events.json');
  $json = json_decode($data, true);

  foreach ($json as $key => $value){
        if ($value > $param1 && $value < $param2) {
              echo "$key => $value"; }
        else { return; }
  }
```

Solution 2 (same parameters passed in, different for each loop):

```
  foreach ($json as $key => $value){
        if ($value >= $param1 && $value <= $param2) { 
              $tempFile = "tempEvents.json";
              $jsonArray = json_decode(file_get_contents($tempFile), true);
              array_push($jsonArray, array( 'title' => ????, 'start' => $param1, 'end' => $param2 ));
              file_put_contents($file, json_encode($jsonArray));
        }
        else { return; }
        echo json_encode('tempEvents.json');
  }
```

Sample JSON file to be parsed:

```
  [
   {
    "Name":"Event 1",
    "Start Time":258147369,
    "End Time":369147258
   },
   {
    "Name":"Event 2",
    "Start Time":789456123,
    "End Time":159487263
   },
  ]
```

Comment: what is your input json and expected output json?

Comment: @Guns the input JSON file that I am parsing is events.json. The expected output JSON would contain only a portion of the original JSON file. I.e, if the values that were passed in for start and end were 15 and 20 respectively, then the new JSON file should only contain events between a start time of 15 and an end time of 20

Answer (score 1):

You should use `json_encode` on an array to get well-formed JSON output. I can't speak for your if statement's validity as you haven't provided any sample data, but this is how you should do your conversion:

```
$param1 = $_GET['startTime'];
$param2 = $_GET['endTime'];
$data = file_get_contents('./events.json');
$json = json_decode($data, true);
$output = array();

foreach ($json as $key => $value){
    if ($value > $param1 && $value < $param2)
        $output[$key] = $value;
}

$json_out = json_encode($output);
echo $json_out; // this outputs to the browser
// to output to file, use $json_out as your string to write to file
```

Comment: As for your Chrome console error - it's a Javascript error. If you post some Javascript, we can work out why it's happening.

Comment: I've added what sample content from the JSON file to be parsed looks like. Essentially, the new JSON file should contain all the info for each event AND only the events that fall within the date range that was passed in through the HTTP GET